# Missing comma error in insert statement

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

```
INSERT INTO Service (Customer_ID,Service_ID,Cost NUMBER) 
VALUES ('CUST001',100,'80');
```

When i try to insert the service details in sql it is showing missing comma error.

Please help me to verify and correct.

Comment: `Cost Number` is not typically a valid column name unless it's quoted or surrounded in brackets. It appears you have a column named `Cost` of type `NUMBER`, and you've used that type in your SQL. Also, if `Cost` is actually type `NUMBER`, it should not have quotes in the value (numbers don't have quotes).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the specific error in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @user3773010, please consider marking an answer (checkbox below the votes) if any of these answered your question.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `Cost NUMBER` column.  Spaces are not supported.

```
INSERT INTO Service (Customer_ID,Service_ID,Cost NUMBER) 
VALUES ('CUST001',100,'80');                ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Some fixes include:

1. Removing `NUMBER` making the column `Cost`.
2. Placing brackets or ticks around the column depending on your platform:

   1. SQL Server would be `[Cost NUMBER]`.
   2. MySql would be `` `Cost NUMBER` ``.

If you are using MS Access or perhaps Oracle, you might be trying to cast to `NUMBER` in which case you would want to cast the value, not the column.

Comment: This would be an answer if you also included information about how to fix the problem.

Comment: @KenWhite, getting there :)

Comment: How do you know that OP isn't trying to use the type `NUMBER`?

Comment: @Kermit, which platforms use the [datatype NUMBER](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp)?

Comment: @Kermit, lol.. its a genuine question, I'm not aware of any and found that reference. Could you enlighten me?

Comment: @paqogomez Microsoft Access.

Comment: @paqogomez, it appears [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) uses the `NUMBER` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

look to the "**Cost Number**" is separate, are you missing a underscope ?

```
INSERT INTO Service (Customer_ID,Service_ID,Cost NUMBER) VALUES ('CUST001',100,'80');
```

Comment: More information is needed from the OP to make this assumption.

Answer (score 0):

What's the datatypes of Service_ID and Cost NUMBER columns? If they're int values, there should be no quotes.

```
INSERT INTO Service ('Customer_ID','Service_ID','Cost NUMBER') VALUES ("CUST001",100,"80");
```

try this if you're sure for datatypes

Comment: More information is needed from the OP to make this assumption.

Comment: You got the quotes the wrong way round: identifiers are quoted using double quotes `"Cost NUMBER"` and string literals require single quotes `'CUST001'`

Answer (score 0):

Cost number is with space. Try writing correct column name without space

Comment: More information is needed from the OP to make this assumption.

Comment: I given an answer to comma problem. Not a sql structure